# API call to get current heap size of process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, heap-memory

I am debugging a slow memory leak in a large C++ application, I'd like to print out the *current* heap size at various points in the program.

Aside from opening and parsing `/proc/PID/statm` is there any library API call from which I can get this information?

One post suggested `sbrk()`, however, that returns the current heap pointer – not 100% what I want. (second question: do changes in the `sbrk()` value correspond to changes in the current heap size?)

I've looked but it seems strange that there'd be no system call...

Thanks

**UPDATE I**

I've done some test comparision between calling `sbrk()` and reading `proc/.../statm`.  It appears that `sbrk()` **does not reflect actual allocations**.  Instead it appears that `statm` measures actual allocations while `sbrk()` shows the total heap size.

This total heapsize increments in big chunks (equal to page size?).

The test program below produces this output (*Heap Size* as reported by `sbrk()` and *memory usage* as reported by `/proc/.../statm`, clearly showing a difference:

```
0 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 0
MEMORY USAGE: 1308 201 174 2 0 566 0
1 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 1565 212 184 2 0 823 0
2 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 1822 216 187 2 0 1080 0
3 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2079 217 187 2 0 1337 0
4 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2336 218 187 2 0 1594 0
5 ALLOC: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2593 219 187 2 0 1851 0

0 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 3364 225 189 2 0 2622 0
1 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 3107 224 189 2 0 2365 0
2 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2850 223 189 2 0 2108 0
3 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2593 222 189 2 0 1851 0
4 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2336 221 189 2 0 1594 0
5 FREE: HEAP SIZE: 135168
MEMORY USAGE: 2079 220 189 2 0 1337 0
```

**Test Program**

```
class CfgProfileList
{
public:
    bool obtainSystemProfileList();
    void leakObjTest();
    std::set<std::string> mProfileList;
private:
    char dummy[1024 * 1024]; // use up some space
};

class ComUtil
{
public:
    static void printMemoryUsage();
private:
    static unsigned int mHeapOrigin;
};

/* static */
unsigned int ComUtil::mHeapOrigin = 0;

// Print current process memory utilization
/* static */ void
ComUtil::printMemoryUsage()
{
    unsigned int pHeap = (unsigned int)sbrk(0);
    if (mHeapOrigin == 0)
        mHeapOrigin = pHeap;

    printf("HEAP SIZE: %u\n", pHeap - mHeapOrigin);

    char fname[256], line[256];
    sprintf(fname, "/proc/%d/statm", getpid());

    FILE *pFile = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!pFile)
        return;    
    fgets(line, 255, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("MEMORY USAGE: %s", line);
}   

void
CfgProfileList::leakObjTest()
{
    CfgProfileList *pointerList[50];
    int  n = 10;
    int  sleep = 100000;

    printf("OBJECT ALLOCATION\n");    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pointerList[i] = new CfgProfileList;
        printf("%d ALLOC: ", i);
        ComUtil::printMemoryUsage();
        usleep(sleep);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete pointerList[i];
        printf("%d FREE: ", i);
        ComUtil::printMemoryUsage();
        usleep(sleep);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CfgProfileList pl;
    pl.leakObjTest();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using valgrind or similar?

Comment: Unfortunately, Valgrind doesn't work; dies with illegal instruction bytes detected. I've asked directly on the valgrind developer list and, following their suggestions, I have since a) rebuild valgrind from source and b) recompiled gcc to the native processor of the target machine. Doesn't work.  Can see related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088970/reliability-of-proc-statm-for-finding-memory-leak

Comment: What is your problem? You have illegal instruction? Maybe a pointer of function invalid? Please add what valgrind print. Seems like a XY problem

Comment: You may use custom allocators( you may need to write a simple one if you're not worried about speed) to check the memory leak. Some place you may also use placement new operator  (which allocate memory from a already allocated memory)

Comment: Stargateur, you can see the full thread on the valgrind list here: https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/valgrind-users/thread/E0EA7B0B-FEFC-4F3B-9BE7-0538F4434653%40torquevideo.tv/#msg35516631  I've given up on valgrind for this project.  I have been having some success with gperftools!

Comment: The fact that `valgrind` does not work should go into the question. It is very relevant

Answer (score 12):

Since glibc's `new` is based on `malloc()`, the malloc information and debugging functions can be used; for example you could add a call of [`malloc_stats()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_stats) to your application.

```
#include <malloc.h>
…
    malloc_stats();
```

> The **malloc_stats**() function prints (on standard error) statistics about memory allocated by
>   ***malloc**(3)* and related functions. …

You might also have a look at

- [`mallinfo()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mallinfo),

  > The **mallinfo**() function returns a copy of a structure containing information about memory allocations performed by **malloc**(3) and related
  >   functions. …
- [**malloc_hook**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_hook),

  > The GNU C library lets you modify the behavior of ***malloc**(3)*, ***realloc**(3)*, and
  >   ***free**(3)* by specifying appropriate hook functions. You can use these hooks to help you debug programs that use dynamic memory allocation, for
  >   example.
- and [`mtrace()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mtrace).

  > The **mtrace**() function installs hook functions for the memory-allocation functions (**malloc**(3), **realloc**(3) **memalign**(3),
  >   **free**(3)). These hook functions record tracing information about memory allocation and deallocation. The tracing information can be used to discover
  >   memory leaks and attempts to free nonallocated memory in a program.

Answer (score 2):

> I am debugging a slow memory leak in a large C++ application

You should try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (after compiling all your code with `-g`). It is a very good tool to track memory leaks (but it does slow down your program by a significant factor, perhaps x3 or x10 at least).

> I'd like to print out the current heap size at various points in the program.

I am not sure that *heap size* has a very well defined meaning (but see other answers to your question). The OS provides and manages the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), and some parts of that are conventionally called "heap". You could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108) (from inside your program) `/proc/self/stat`, `/proc/self/statm`, `/proc/self/status`, `/proc/self/maps`, and this can be quick. Also use the [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) commands (all using `/proc/` internally). The [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & `munmap`, [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) (and old [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)) [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)s can change your virtual address space. the C++ `new` uses `malloc` which often use `mmap`. However, `free` or `delete` often mark a released memory zone as reusable by future `malloc`-s but don't give up the memory to the system.

PS. If `valgrind` is not working, my guess is that you have corrupted your memory, which is even more bad than just a memory leak. Consider trying some sanitizer (and other [instrumentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)), perhaps the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Of course enable all warnings and debug info (so compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and take time to improve the source code to get *no* warnings at all. Recent GCC compilers (so GCC 8 in august 2018) gives better warnings and have improved sanitizrs than older ones, so it could be worth to update your `g++` compiler.